# Ordering data through SQL Select query in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo

I have a All India Village tab file(6Lac records) and an excel which has information on most of those villages(4Lac records).

I want to select 100 villages from a particular state whose area is the highest.

I used the below shown query:
[image]

But in this query the Area is sorted after selecting first 100 records. I want to select 100 records which have the highest area.

Is there a way the villages are ordered first as per the area and then the selection is carried out?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do two queries.

In the first one: Same as yours, but remove "(Rowid<=100) And"

Then, secondly, query the 'Selection' table to show where Rowid<=100

Comment: How to query the selection table? Do I have to save it as a new table first?

Comment: No, you can query the Selection table, or a named query result just like querying a base table